# Cramér-Rao regular model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cramer-rao

Why is the fact that the support of each $f$ belonging to a Cramér-Rao regular model does not depend on the parameter implied by the condition that the derivative with respect to the parameter of $f $ exist for every $x$ and every parameter belonging to the parameter space? Or better why an indicator depending on the parameter (as in the case when the support depends on the parameter) is not differentiable with respect to the parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Let me remind you of the bare minimum assumptions needed for the exchange of derivative and integral:

Let $(\mathbb R, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak M}_L, \mu_L) $ be the Lebesgue measure space. Let $I\subseteq \mathbb R$ be open in $\mathbb R$ and let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be open in $\mathbb R^n, n\geq 1.$ Let $h$ be a real-valued function defined on $I\times \Omega$ such that $\frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma_i} h(  \boldsymbol\gamma,x), ~i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ exists for all $(\boldsymbol\gamma\times x) \in  \Omega\times I.$ Assume

$\mathrm A1. $ $h(\boldsymbol\gamma, \cdot) $ is $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak M}_L$-measurable on $I$ for each $\boldsymbol\gamma \in \Omega.$

$\mathrm A2. $ $h(\boldsymbol\gamma_0, \cdot) $ is $\mu_L$-integrable on $I$ for some $\boldsymbol\gamma_0\in \Omega.$

$\mathrm A3. $ There exists a non-negative extended real-valued $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak M}_L$-measurable and $\mu_L$-integrable function $\psi$ on $I$ such that $\left\vert \frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma_i} h(  \boldsymbol\gamma,x)\right\vert \leq \psi(x) $ for all $(\boldsymbol\gamma\times x) \in\Omega\times I. $

Then

$\bullet$ $h(\boldsymbol\gamma, \cdot) $ is $\mu_L$ integrable on $I$ for some $\boldsymbol\gamma_0\in \Omega.$

$\bullet$ $\frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma_i} h(  \boldsymbol\gamma,x)$ is $\boldsymbol{\mathfrak M}_L$-measurable and $\mu_L$-integrable on $I$ for each $\boldsymbol\gamma\in \Omega.$

$\bullet$ Define the real-valued function on $\Omega, ~H(\boldsymbol\gamma) :=\int_I h(\boldsymbol \gamma, \cdot) ~\mathrm d\mu_L(x). ~H$ is differentiable at $\boldsymbol\gamma$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma_i} H(\boldsymbol \gamma)=\int_I\frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma_i} h(  \boldsymbol\gamma,\cdot)~\mathrm d\mu_L(x).$

Note the assumptions required: the partial derivative of $h$ with respect to $\gamma_i$ needs to exist on $\Omega\times I. $

However, consider  (cf. $\rm [II]$) $\gamma\in\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R$ and define $$g(\gamma, x) :=\begin{cases}\exp(\gamma-x)& x\geq \gamma,\\ 0&x<\gamma.\end{cases}$$ It fails to satisfy $\rm A3. $ More importantly, the support is not independent of $\gamma.$

Secondly, take the conventional example used for irregular statistical experiments: $\mathcal U[0, \theta].$ The support is not independent of $\theta.$ However, $\frac{\partial f(\theta, ~x) }{\partial \theta}$ does exist.

Either $f(\gamma, x) \ne 0$ for each $\gamma~\mu_L$-$\mathrm{a.e.}$ or the support should be independent of $\gamma$ (cf. $\rm [III]$).

Failure of this would lead to the nonexistence of derivative in the sense that the $\mathcal L_2$ norm of $\left\Vert \partial \sqrt{f(\theta, ~\cdot)}/\partial\theta\right\Vert_2$ is finite - $\mathcal U[0, \theta]$ isn't differentiable (cf. $\rm [IV]$).

---

### References:

$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, *James J. Yeh,* World Scientific, $2014, $ Proposition $23.37, $ pp. $574-575.$

$\rm [II]$ Mathematical Methods of Statistics, *Harold Cramér*, Princeton University Press, $1946, $ Theorem $7.3.\rm II, $ pp. $66-67.$

$\rm [III]$ Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, *Leopold Schmetterer, Kenneth Wickwire* (Trans.), Springer-Varleg, $1974, $ p. $284.$

$\rm [IV]$ Mathematical Statistics: Asymptotic Minimax Theory, *Alexander Korostelev, Olga Korosteleva,* AMS, $2011, $ Theorem $4.3, $ pp. $44-45.$